# Projecting Imported NetCDF file correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, import, netcdf

I have 360 NetCDF files (.nc) that I need to import into ArcGIS.

They hold monthly historical climate data in the U.S.

When I tried to import one, using the Make NETCDF Raster Layer tool, the projection doesn't seem to register at all, just places the data on the point (0,0).

Any ideas?

I am new to ArcGIS.

Comment: Might be difficult based on the size, but are you able to upload one of these .nc files? Additionally, does the NetCDF data display correctly in other viewers, such as [Panoply](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/)?

Comment: Hello!  I am able to upload the file into Arc fine, it just doesn't project right.  I've never used Panoply before.  I am able to view the contents of the file there fine, but it doesn't allow me to 'Create Plot' - probably since I have no clue what I'm doing.  Is there a way I can send you one of the files to try?

Comment: do you know what the correct projection should be? have you checked the details of the projection in the NetCDF file? you may want to check out http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/software.html for tools to interact with the NetCDF

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue here might be the way the data is imported not the projection.

If you use the Multidimension Tools tool box in ArcGIS 10.0, you need to enter the dimensions of your netcdf variable as the "Row Dimension" option in order to plot the value at each coordinate.